# Apply all transformation issue

Tags: modeling, origin, transform-orientation

I have received this file from a friend and I can't understand the issue that is happening when applying all transformations. (attaching the file)

[image]

Two pots on the left has a strange behaviour when applying transformation, they rotate and the origin point moves up from the world origin, the blue pot behaves as expected.
I wouldn't mind that much, but I need those assets for a GLB scene and when exported the object moves. There is a workaround, but I wonder what is going on.

Appreciate the help

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have delta transforms:

[image]

To clear deltas, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>(<kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>) → <kbd>F9</kbd> (Adjust last operation) → **Clear delta**

If you want to keep current position, I could recommend press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> → **rotation**, then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> → <kbd>F9</kbd> → **Clear delta** to rotate back.

Comment: Perfect :) thanks a lot, Had no clue what Delta transform meant. Thanks again. https://www.oneminutevideotutorials.com/2014/12/29/blender-understanding-delta-transforms/